# how to get in between months and year in react js?

Tags: reactjs, antd

If user selects the in between months and year it will be stored in an object(look like Month picker)

i tried Range picker in ant design but it will get only starting and ending month only i want to store all in between months in an array(object)

```
 <RangePicker
        placeholder={['Start month', 'End month']}
        format="YYYY-MM"
        value={value}
        mode={mode}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onPanelChange={this.handlePanelChange}
      />
```

output ["2019-01,"2019-02,"2019-03"]

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateStart = moment('2013-8-31');
var dateEnd = moment('2015-3-30');
var timeValues = [];

while (dateEnd > dateStart || dateStart.format('M') === dateEnd.format('M')) {
   timeValues.push(dateStart.format('YYYY-MM'));
   dateStart.add(1,'month');
}
```